# Does my task scheduler still running if i run it using Cron job every 15 minutes

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, lumen

so I have a job that should run every minute. But one of the rules in my hosting provider is "Cron job should run at least once every 15 minutes". My question is does my task scheduler still running within the next 15 minutes? if no, any ideas to make it runs every minute? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ... "cron job should run at least 15 minutes" doesn't make any sense

Comment: It normally runs every minute, usually set in crontab, assuming unix system, try `crontab -e` in the console

Comment: I suppose you mean the cron only runs once every 15 minutes? In that case, your job will also run every 15 minutes.

Comment: ah yeah i mean the cron only runs once every 15 minutes